# What stanzas in Vyasa Mahabharata convey that Sri Krishna held Bhishma as adharmic or protecting adharma?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, bhishma

In Gita, Sri Krishna  tells Arjuna that Bheeshma, Drona & Karna were already slain by him, so Arjuna shouldn't worry and just kill his enemies. That is a very indirect message.

Were there other instances where Sri Krishna explicitly mentions his displeasure on Bheeshma's conduct (silence during draupdai disrobement for example)?

Comment: Yes during visit to Hastinapur he says the same to bishma and Dronacharya that he cannot come to their home as they were silent during drupadi vastrabharana